# Obtaining OAuth access token from identity server within Xamarin application

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, oauth-2.0

Within a Xamarin application I have created, I'm trying to connect to a Web API which I'm running locally in a separate solution. In order to successfully connect to this API I have to retrieve an access token from the identity server endpoint (OAuth 2.0).

I'm currently finding it very difficult to find a solution that allows me to retrieve this token.

In existing .NET projects I have used the following code to retrieve the access token but in the Xamarin App this does not work, it hits the first line and comes back 5 minutes later saying it was cancelled:

```
try
{
   var disco = await httpClient.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync(new DiscoveryDocumentRequest
   {
       Address = clientCredentials.Path,
       Policy =
       {
          RequireHttps = false
       }
   });

   if (disco.IsError) Console.WriteLine(disco.Error);

   var tokenResponse = await httpClient.RequestClientCredentialsTokenAsync(newClientCredentialsTokenRequest
   {
       Address = "https://<local-machine-ip>:<port-of-auth-localhost>/connect/token",
       ClientId = clientCredentials.ClientId,
       ClientSecret = clientCredentials.ClientSecret,
       Scope = clientCredentials.Scope
   });

   if (tokenResponse.IsError) Console.WriteLine(tokenResponse.Error);

   httpClient.SetBearerToken(tokenResponse.AccessToken);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

The closest I have got is through this code, but this returns the 'Error: TrustFailure (Authentication failed, see inner exception.)':

```
var client = new RestClient("https://<local-machine-ip>:<port-of-auth-localhost>/connect/token");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=xxxx&client_secret=xxxxx&scope=xxxxx", ParameterType.RequestBody);

IRestResponse response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);
```

I'm running out of ideas at this point, does anyone know of a solution?

Just to note I am running xamarin.android the android emulator. The code shown above currently sits in a class within the ClassLibrary of the xamarin.forms solution

Comment: This sample maybe helpful. You could check it. https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth

Comment: Thanks @WendyZang-MSFT I will check the sample out. I managed to get the access token in the end by using the 10.0.2.2 as my IP Address however, when I used the access token to call my API method the token author was invalid. So fingers crossed the sample helps

Answer (score 1):

`locahost` is the emulator itself, not the PC that is hosting the emulator, use 10.0.2.2 instead to "reach" the hosting PC.

> Also note that the address 127.0.0.1 on your development machine corresponds to the emulator's own loopback interface. If you want to access services running on your development machine loopback interface (a.k.a. 127.0.0.1 on your machine), you should use the special address 10.0.2.2 instead.

Set up Android Emulator networking : https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking

Comment: Thank you for the help @SushiHangover - so would my client be: `var client = new RestClient("http://10.0.2.2:<local auth server port>/connect/token");`? I have tried this but I get the following error: "Unable to read data from the transport connection: The socket has been shut down."